# My character has a healing ability. Would drugs work on him?

Tags: humans, super-powers

I have a character with the ability to quickly heal himself and others of most illnesses and diseases.

I want to write a scene where he’s drugged with a sleeping medication (melatonin, or something stronger).

Would his body get rid by itself of any drug or just harmful toxins in his system? Would his body even register it as harmful (he doesn’t realize he’s begin drugged)? I don’t know how to go about this.

Comment: That depends on how you define the healing power of your character. You yourself have healing powers, it just takes a while. Is your character like that but just faster? Magic? (Nano-)technology? Decide how the healing works to get the answer you want for your story.

Comment: Heh. A friend of mine has a mirror reaction to caffeine. It puts him to sleep. Probably *different* drugs will work on your character in different ways.

Comment: This seems primarily story-based. I would reformat this question to something like: My characters ability works like this, why does X still work on him? With a little refinement this looks like a cool first question!

Answer (score 7):

It's entirely up to you and how you want to frame the healing ability.

Last week I ripped my finger on a sharp metallic edge, and now it's no longer bleeding and new skin is growing to close the cut. I (and 7+ other billion humans) have this healing ability, and I can be drugged, else I couldn't have been to the dentist last month to have a tooth pulled without the blink of an eye.

But you are talking about super-powers here, so it's, again, entirely up to you and what you want in your story.

Answer (score 2):

"has the ability to quickly heal himself and others" sounds like this power requires a conscious act of your character. In this case, he'll be susceptible to drugs just like anyone else as long as he doesn't realize in time he's been drugged.

But in the end, i'd recommend you define the capabilities and boundaries of your superpower first, and then derive possible attack vectors from those.

Answer (score 1):

Melatonin is a naturally occuring hormone in the human body and regulates the sleep cycle as well as some other fun stuff.   The over the counter sleep supplements are designed to increase the concentration and induce sleep in the user.  Since it occurs naturally, your body wouldn't see it as a threat and thus healing agents wouldn't be dispatched to handle it ordinarily and it's waste products are disposed of through normal waste disposal methods (urination, sweat, exhaled breaths).

Additionally, sleep is an important function for healing both physical and mental healing.